# Why my LAN connection is so slow?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I transfer files from one computer to another by LAN connection. Exact configuration looks like this:
- laptop ==> [ WIFI ] => router => [ cable LAN ] ==> desktop PC

- this WIFI connection has "nominal" speed of 54 Mb/s
- LAN is 100 Mb/s

Maximum transfer speed I get is somewhere around 12 Mb/s thous 1.5 MB/s.

Why can't I reach this 54 Mb/s or at least something more then 12 Mb/s ? What can be the problem?

**OS: Windows XP**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to look at this article.
http://articles.marco.org/127

It shows how much encryption affects Network transfer speeds. You don't mention it but I would imagine you are using some form of encryption on your wireless network.
Also is shows how far away from getting the 100% 54MB/s speeds consumer hardware actually is.

Plus then you have to look at other bottlenecks in the ecosystem. other Hardware, activities that could be slowing down the transfer speeds.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that all of your devices are supporting 802.11g ( or n ). It would appear something may still be running 802.11b, as the theoretical fastest throughput for 802.11b is 11 Mbps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying if you are behind a physical wall and the wifi card you are using in your laptop. If you're using a wifi adapter which includes an antenna you can make the antenna point torward the router. Try updating or replacing the wifi card.

Try doing other combinations:

a) laptop ==> [ cable LAN ] => router => [ wifi ] ==> desktop PC

b) laptop <== [ cable LAN ] <= router <= [ wifi ] <== desktop PC

c) laptop <== [ wifi ] <= router <= [ cable LAN ] <== desktop PC

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).